# "Treffen" with "sein" rather than "haben"?

Tags: verb, past

What does this mean?

> "Grace" war als Hurrikan auf die mexikanische Golfküste getroffen und hatte über Land dann rasch an Kraft verloren.

Source : https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/hurrikan-grace-mexiko-103.html

I don't understand the war and getroffen part. Perhaps it means that it "had hit the Mexican Gulf coast as a Hurricane". It just sounds very weird.

I do see here (https://www.verbformen.com/conjugation/treffen.htm) that it can be used with sein.

Answer (score 6):

*Treffen* can have a broad range of meanings ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/treffen) lists 8) and it can be used with an accusative object or with *auf* + accusative.

In most cases, the perfect uses *haben*.

However, when used with *auf* in the meaning of 'to hit, to encounter', which is the case here, *sein* must be used.

Answer (score 5):

The verb is not *treffen* but *auf etw. treffen*. This classifies it as a verb of motion, thus it is conjugated with *sein*. I believe it's mostly used in the past tense, i.e. "auf etwas/jemanden getroffen sein", alhough *planemaker* mentions in the comments that other tense are possible and in frequent use.

I concur, that the above sentence sounds a bit weird. An arguably better way might be

> Der Hurrikan "Grace" war auf die mexikanische Golfküste getroffen und hatte über Land dann rasch an Kraft verloren".

In either case, the translation literally means the hurricane "met" the land, although "hit" seems the more fitting translation.

Comment: It doesn't sound so weird to me. "War als Hurrikan ... getroffen" means that it was only classified as a hurricane when it reached the land, before it lost force and was downgraded to a tropical storm.

Comment: Also, I don't see why *auf etw. treffen* should not be used in other tenses when describing a current event or a future event (e.g., in a weather forecast)

Comment: "Wenn ihr einen bisher unerforschten Teil des Regenwaldes betretet, könntet ihr auch auf Ureinwohner treffen, die bisher noch keinen Kontakt mit der Außenwelt hatten". Das Verb 'auf etwas/jemanden treffen' lebt in allen Zeitformen und wird auch so genutzt

Answer (score 2):

"war ... getroffen" and "hatte ... verloren" are [plusquamperfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect) forms. And yes, it sounds weird because it shoud not be used here.

Your translation

> "Grace" had hit the Mexican Gulf coast as a Hurricane

is adequate. A correct German sentence would be

> "Grace" traf als Hurrikan auf die mexikanische Golfküste und verlor über Land dann rasch an Kraft.

An alternative is

> "Grace" war als Hurrikan auf die mexikanische Golfküste getroffen, bevor sie über Land dann rasch an Kraft verlor.

This expresses the fact that there is a temporal succession: Grace lost  power when it was over land (past tense), but **before** that it hit the coast (plusquamperfect).

Comment: If you think the pluperfect is incorrect, you should give a reason. I see none.

Comment: @DavidVogt Do you seriously want that I include a grammar lecture about the use of  plusquamperfect? Isn't the link in my answer sufficient? Quotation: " ... relating to an action that occurred antecedent to a contextually aforementioned time in the past".

Comment: *War getroffen* is antecedent to everything mentioned in the first half of the article. Therefore, the pluperfect seems to have been used correctly.

Comment: @DavidVogt I think it is gramatically and  stilistically messy.  *"Grace" war als Hurrikan auf die mexikanische Golfküste getroffen und hatte über Land dann rasch an Kraft verloren. Allerdings prognostizierte der Wetterdienst für weite Teile des Landes heftigen Regen und warnte vor Erdrutschen und Überschwemmungen.* So the forecast came after the arrival and the passing of the hurricane?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, the forecast came after because it isn't about the hurricane (as indicated by "Der Notstand ist nicht vorbei."). Everything the hurricane did is in the first half of the article and the sentence with the pluperfect introduces an antecedent to that.

Comment: @DavidVogt It is well-known that tropical storms are accompanied by heavy rainfall. Forecasts contain this information. See [this](https://www.washingtonpost.com/weather/2021/08/20/hurricane-grace-mexico-landfall-wind-surge-flooding/): *In addition to the risk of dangerous storm surge and damaging winds, heavy rains are set to trace the track inland and potentially induce flooding. Four to 12 inches of rain are likely to fall across the region as the storm makes landfall.  Totals of up to 18 inches are anticipated, particularly in mountainous terrain that Grace will travel over as it heads*

Comment: *deeper into Mexico. Dangerous flash flooding and mudslides are also likely.*

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm just following what the article says. The first part describes consequences (2) that occured after the storm made landfall (1). To indicate that the temporal order is as indicated by the numbers, the sentence in question uses the pluperfect. The article then switches back to the simple past, i.e. to events that are contemporaneous or subsequent to (2). *Prognostizierte* cannot be contemporaneous to (1). I'm not saying that there were no prognoses before (1), just that the prognosis mentioned in the article isn't one of those.

Comment: @DavidVogt So let us agree that we do not agree ;-) And probably it is not that important to be right.

Answer (score 0):

There's two pages about treffen. "treffen" and "treffen_ist". Check out this one:
https://www.verbformen.com/conjugation/treffen_ist.htm

Your translation with "had hit" sounds pretty accurate.